# UMBRACO troubles - Ecommerce Integration

Tags: html, razor, e-commerce, umbraco

I am trying to add some form of ecommerce to our website www.lightfab.com

I was going to simply insert the html tags for the paypal button that I had but the html editor clips the code and doesn't insert what I want. I was told that I may need to use XSLT or Razor macros... but I would have to make one for each product that I want to use... also I don't know how to use XSLT or Razor.

Is there a simple way to either integrate some form of ecommerce or a way to enable html input for pages?!

Thanks!

Comment: Need a bit of clarification on your question. Which HTML editor are you talking about? e.g. Richtext Editor, Template Editor. And what do you mean by "clips"? Some before & after code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed buttons from PayPal is definitely one possibility, but they are just that "fixed", which means that you'd have to create a button for each product. If you're dealing with a limited number of products it might be a good way to go.

Another approach is to use an e-commerce extension for Umbraco like [uCommerce](http://www.ucommerce.dk). It does the integration with PayPal for you and doesn't cost a thing to use. You will have to get your hands dirty with some code, but you'll get a full set e-commerce functionality for free with it.